# multiplying two array in python3.7

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to multiply two array in python 3.7 using numpy by using the following syntax:

```
array1 = np.array([{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}]) 
print (array1)  
array2=array1*array1 
print(array2)
```

but this error arises

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'set' and 'set'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply defining your array so that it is made of python `set`s. That is a different data structure which is not able to be  multiplied, unlike an array.

Just change your code to this:

```
array1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

The only difference is using square brackets instead of curly ones. These are python `list` objects (or standard arrays).

```
array2=array1*array1  
print(array2)

[[ 1  4  9 16]
 [25 36 49 64]]
```